Firebase docData stream emits identical object values multiple times in a row
This is my code:
import { doc, docData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

const gameDocRef = doc(this.firestore, 'game', game.id);
const game$ = docData(gameDocRef, { idField: 'id' })

Somehow the game$ observable emits two identical emissions in a row
Some things to note:

I am logging and checking: the stream only gets created once
I am logging and checking: the same exact deep-copy object gets emitted two times
I am only doing a single request to my firestore-backend and yet this request causes two identical emissions

Of course I could do a distinctUntilXChanged on the observable, but afaik this will still count them as two distinct reads in my firestore quota. This is the main problem I am trying to avoid, I do not want to pay twice as much money for firestore than I actually need to.
This is how I am determining whether the emissions are identical:
        const currentGameJSON = JSON.stringify(currentGame);
        const newGameJSON = JSON.stringify(game);
        if (currentGameJSON === newGameJSON) {
          console.error("SAME GAME EMISSION", currentGameJSON);
        }

My doc does not have recursive props or anything weird like this, simple JSON.
I do not have firestore persistence enabled.
edit:
Actually I am now using this deepEqual check, to check for game duplicates:
function deepEqual(obj1: any, obj2: any): boolean {
  if (obj1 === obj2) return true;

  if (typeof obj1 !== 'object' || obj1 === null || typeof obj2 !== 'object' || obj2 === null) {
    return false;
  }

  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) return false;

  for (let key of keys1) {
    if (!keys2.includes(key)) return false;

    if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object' && typeof obj2[key] === 'object') {
      if (!deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[key])) return false;
    } else if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}


do you have SSR enabled?

No I do not have SSR enabled.

please share github repo where the issue happens for debugging, also explain the steps to replicate the issue.

hey I added a minimum reproducible example. I made it really easy to recognize it. It emits the same game twice after a single update. Check the question again (a mod needs to approve it first, here u go: https://github.com/folsze/firebase-observable-double-emission)

The value is updated locally (fires observable once) once before sending to the database (fires observable second), which gives the impression that there are two emits and multiple saves to the database. But I found a reference answer by Tim Thompson which solved this problem using distinctUntilChanged being added to the observable stream, so that there is a single emissions.
If you set offline to the network tab, and trigger an update, you will see the observable is fired without even any save to the database.
private getGameDocData(gameId: string, currentUserId: string): Observable<Game | null> {
    const gameDocRef = doc(this.firestore, 'games', gameId);

    const game$ = docData(gameDocRef, { idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(), // <- Changed here!
      map(data => (data ? (data as Game) : null)),
      tap((data) => {
        console.log(" intrinsic stream emission:", data);
      })
    );
    ...


Great thanks for this finding. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem as the distinctUntilChanged needs to be used with deepEquals in my case as my games are objects not values. And using deepEquals this would cause great client overhead, since games can contain arrays of over 100 users in my app. Is there a different way of solving this?

@frontend-ux-ui from what I can see, distinctUntilChanged is enough which stops the multiple emissions so there is no need for that deepEquals check

@frontend-ux-ui as an alternative, try debounceTIme, which is also effective in getting rid of multiple emissions

Thanks for this suggestion. It did not come to my mind. And this would also not cause a risk of loosing a final "game ended" emission since it will always display the latest emitted value, just skip intermediate ones, correct?
